# Группировка и сортировка сразу нескольких столбцов

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица с данными по тв-приставке от оператора связи, из которых нужно составить отчет, где `id`-id пакета, `mac`-макадрес приставки, `dttm`-время в unix формате, `event`-событие(в данном отрывке `channel-switch`-переключение канала) и `details`-номер канала, на который собственно и произошло переключение).

Мне нужно выбрать одинаковые строчки `mac`, внутри которых отсортировать по `dttm`, чтобы просмотр длился не менее 5 минут и не более 120 минут (только этот промежуток времени считается за просмотр канала). Время отсчета этих минут идут только по строчкам последовательно внутри одного мак-адреса (т.е. человек при переключении на канал не остался на нем на нужное время, значит он не идет в счет). Потом данные о том, сколько человек смотрело определенный канал необходимо вывести при запросе администратора, причем запрашивает он определенный промежуток времени.

А теперь вопрос - возможно ли хоть что-то из этого сделать в sql или здесь уже понадобится php, и, если да, то подскажите хоть какой то вероятный план действий - куда мне стоит двигаться, чтобы решить этот вопрос? Изначальная таблица с данными представлена ниже и спасибо за внимание.

```
INSERT INTO `ttv_stats` (`id`, `mac`, `from`, `dttm`, `event`, `details`) VALUES
(8315410, 'E4:AB:46:00:22:C0', 0, 1353355207, 'channel_switch', 'id=202'),
(8315411, 'E4:AB:46:00:22:C0', 0, 1353355210, 'channel_switch', 'id=200000'),
(8315416, 'E4:AB:46:00:33:F2', 0, 1353355207, 'channel_switch', 'id=214'),
(8315417, 'E4:AB:46:00:33:F2', 0, 1353355216, 'channel_switch', 'id=324'),
(8315418, 'E4:AB:46:00:33:F2', 0, 1353355249, 'channel_switch', 'id=325'),
(8315419, 'E4:AB:46:00:33:F2', 0, 1353355557, 'channel_switch', 'id=1009'),
...
```

Comment: *возможно ли хоть что-то из этого сделать в sql* Несомненно. И не что-то, а всё. Особенно если точная версия MySQL - 8.0.xx.

Comment: См. напр. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c01563a15537dc86ed7639b5e081ef9